# Query a database based on form input then output to another page

Tags: wp-query, database, forms

I have minimal WordPress/Web dev experience so I’m trying to figure out the best way to do this.

Background: I’m an outside salesmen with a company that sells water treatment equipment. We test water at the shop and use that information to size the best possible system for the customer.

What I’m trying to do: I currently have a Wordpress site running that I’ve been messing around with. I want to have a page that I can insert my test results in, submit those results to query the database for the proper product, then output the results and the best product available from the database on a clean page. That way I can print the page out and hand it to my customers.

I’ve been looking around at a couple different Wordpress plugins but I’m unsure the best way to handle this. Hopefully you guys can help.

Comment: Without knowing more, it sounds like you may need to hire a developer. There are plugins that would let you create a form, but they wouldn't search for products. You might be able to use an ecommerce plugin like WooCommerce that lets you search for products, but you would need to set up products in a way that they include the attributes you would be searching on, and would need to make sure the search form supports searching by those attributes and not just by product name.

Comment: I’m new to Web Dev but I’m familiar with programming. Upon looking further into I’ll probably just do it in PHP. It doesn’t have to be a plug-in, I would be able to code it I was just looking for a point in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the *way* you could handle it, though opinions may vary.  Getting the framework up will be a bit complicated and making it pretty is another task entirely.

I would make it sexy by running an AJAX query when you submit the form.  The AJAX script collects all the data from the boxes on the page, makes the call to the back end, then renders visible a "Results:" box that was on the page the whole time, and inserts the resulting HTML into that box.  That's how slick search results work, basically.

The results box has a button to create a PDF.  Java is watching that button and what that button has is a data-attribute holding, probably, the very same HTML that was in the results box.  You have inserted that HTML simultaneously when you inserted it into the results box.  So now Java can send that data-attr to the PDF writer without hitting the back end again.  This will come out as the "clean screen" you asked for, but even better can be downloaded or emailed. :)

Here is an example java function that creates a form, appends an object to the form and then submits the form.  You would submit this to your "PDF Writer" script.  You populate the object (obj) submitted to this function with all the data you want to submit - probably just your html but the possibilities are endless.

```
function submitACP(obj){
        // form submission to ACP with current vars     
        var scheduleForm = document.createElement("form");
        scheduleForm.id = "transmission_form";
        scheduleForm.target = "_self";
        scheduleForm.method = "post"; // or "POST" if appropriate
        scheduleForm.enctype = "multipart/form-data";
        if (isset(obj.clientID) && obj.clientID > 0) {
            scheduleForm.action = 'https://'+$(location).attr('host')+'/create-pdf/'; 
        } else {
            scheduleForm.action = 'https://'+$(location).attr('host')+'/client-selector/'; // need a client id
        }
        var transmissionData = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj));
        console.log('data stringified:'+transmissionData);

        var transmission_object = document.createElement("input");
        transmission_object.type = "text";
        transmission_object.name = "client_object";
        transmission_object.value = transmissionData;
        scheduleForm.appendChild(transmission_object);

        document.body.appendChild(scheduleForm);

        $('#transmission_form').submit();
    }
```

For a PDF writer I use TCPDF.  It takes a lot of trial and error to get it right, but it's solid.  First thing you do is start output buffering to prevent anything ruining your PDF.  Then you run your logic, capturing whatever you want into a string variable. Stop the buffering, then require the TCPDF directories and invoke it:

```
ob_start();
set_time_limit(30);

$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
//define( 'SHORTINIT', true );
require( $path.'/wp-load.php' );

$data_array = json_decode(stripslashes(urldecode($_POST['client_object'] )), true );

if (! wp_verify_nonce($data_array['nonce'], 'pdf_nonce')) {
    die('sorry, charlie.');
}
$doc_label = wp_kses($data_array['client_name']);
echo wp_kses($data_array['html']);

// Include the main TCPDF library (search for installation path).
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/tcpdf/config/tcpdf_config.php';
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/tcpdf/tcpdf.php';

// create new PDF document
ob_end_clean();
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Sales Robot');
$pdf->SetTitle($doc_label);
$pdf->SetSubject('Hardcopy Schedule');
//$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO);

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 20);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

//$pdf->Write(0, 'Example of HTML tables', '', 0, 'L', true, 0, false, false, 0);

$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 12);

$pdf->writeHTML($hc_html, true, false, false, false, '');
$doc_label .= '.pdf';
//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output($doc_label, 'I');

//============================================================+
// END OF FILE
//============================================================+

die();
?>
```

So like I said, you can come at this from a number of directions.  If you don't have a handle on java and AJAX you can just submit a form to your PDF writer page, which, after starting the output buffer!, runs the logic on your form variables, outputs to a variable and then uses the variable in the invocation of the PDF writer.

Comment: Thank you so much! You really went above and beyond with this one and I appreciate that. Your ideas were awesome and I think that’s exactly how I’ll do it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well if you're happy could you mark it as the accepted answer so I get the credit?  Thanks!  I need rep points.